# Create function to loop through a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, function, loops, sum

I have a dataframe that looks like this. [image]

Now i want to **create a function** to get the sum of the 'Total' column for each of the name 'ABC','XYZ'... with a pre-defined condition of the Currency.
In other words, i want my output to be the same as the following[image]

```
Name_list = list(df['Name'])
Currency_list = list(df['Currency'])

def Calculation(a,b):
    for a in Name_list:
        for b in Currency_list:
            return df['Total'].sum()

result = Calculation('ABC','VND')
print(result)
```

So far what I have got is just the sum of the whole column 'Total'. Anyone has ideas how to get the desired result for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think pandas' `groupby` method may help you here:

```py
df.groupby(['Currency', 'Name'])['Total'].sum()
```

Link to official docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is actually nothing that force the function to use only the lines you want to select in your dataframe.
This can be done by using the `loc` function to locate the lines you want to sum on.

In your example, if you replace le the line `return df['Total'].sum()` by this one :
`return df.loc[(df['Name'] == a) & (df['Currency'] == b), 'Total').apply(numpy.sum)`
It should return what you want.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. However, it only returns a fixed value, even though I have tried to insert different arguments to the function.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think it will work with this line (you need to import numpy though).